# Using user input to define array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a project where I need to create a shopping list with checkout functionality. I am trying to create an array using a users input. They supply how many products they are purchasing and I need to use that to define the size of the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct shopList {
    double pluCode;
    string product;
    int saleType; // 0 = per unit, 1 = per pound
    double price;
    double inventory;


};

int main(){

    char line[255];
    const int items = 0;
    int n;

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("products.txt");

    cout << "How many items in your checkout: ";
    cin >> items;

    shopList shop[items];

    for (n = 0; n < items; n++) {
        cout << "Enter the PLU code: ";
        cin >> shop.pluCode;
        outfile << shop.pluCode << " ";

        cout << "Enter product name: ";
        cin >> shop.product;
        outfile << shop.product << " ";

        cout << "Enter the price type (0 for per unit, 1 for per pound): ";
        cin >> shop.saleType;
        outfile << shop.saleType << " ";

        cout << "Enter the price of the product: ";
        cin >> shop.price;
        outfile << shop.price << " ";

        cout << "How much will you purchase: ";
        cin >> shop.inventory;
        outfile << shop.inventory << " " << "\n";

    }



    outfile.close();

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("products.txt");
    infile.getline(line, 255);
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that in standard C++. Use `std::vector` (or possibly allocate using `new`)

Comment: Don't use `char[255]`.  Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm quite sure _"can't do that in standard C++"_ is false. You've said why in your own comment.

Comment: @PawełStawarz: No, you can't use variable length arrays in C++. There are ALTERNATIVE solutions that solve the same problem.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I can't agree with you. There's no mention about VLAs in the question itself, you're judging that's the case only because of how the author tried to implement it. The question is _"I need to use that [user input] to define the size of the array."_, and the answer most certainly isn't "can't do that" :)

Comment: I think your definition of "can do" and mine is different - you can not size an array in C++ with value that isn't a compile-time constant. There are OTHER ways to achieve that goal, but that involves dynamic allocation, which is not the same as a sizing an array at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible ,  you  just have  to change your  declaration like that;

int  items = 0 ;
 cin >> items;

```
shopList *shop =  new  shopList [items];
```

Comment: Remember to use `delete [] shop;` to deallocate the array.

Comment: @sexobert How would I change "cin >> shop.pluCode;" to adjust? It is giving me "Error: expression must have class type".

Comment: Of course , don't forget  to  " delete [] shop  "   after using  your  array

Comment: @AaronHavenar ,  your  variable shop is  a  pointer  to a  shopList array.
shop  is  an  array,  so  you  must  do some  thing like  that  shop[n].pluCode    (where  i is  a counter)     instead of  shop.pluCode;

Comment: @AaronHavenar

You have  to use  this syntax  everywhere  you  want to  use your  array.
shop[n]."witch  attributes  of  your shopList structure"  ;